# Ordenar apresentação de ficheiros consoante a extenção

Tags: php

Eu tenho um código onde quero mostrar os ficheiros que estão inseridos.

Os nomes estão contidos num `array` que vou buscar à base de dados. Eles são apresentados da forma que eu quero mas existe alguma forma de ordenar? Como por exemplo aparecer as imagens primeiro e depois os outros sem extenções? Tenho assim o meu código.

```
<?php
$count=explode(",", $mos['files']);
foreach($count as $i){
  $ext=substr($i, strpos($i, ".") + 1);
  if($ext=="png" || $ext=="PNG" || $ext=="jpg" || $ext=="JPEG" || $ext=="JPG" || $ext=="jpeg"){
    echo '<img src="../images/documentos/'.$i.'" />';
  }else{
    echo '<li>'.$i.'</li>';
  }
}
?>
```

Dou como exemplo o seguinte `array`: `ajax.png,array.pdf,algo.jpg,tres.docx,sentido.doc`

Comment: tem um exemplo do `array` ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Adicionei informação à pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem sim, basta usar [**`usort`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), assim:

```
<?php

$arquivos = array("semext", "apple.doc", "foo.png", "apple.txt", "foo.png", "banana.jpg", "apple.txt");

function is_image_extension($name) {
     return preg_match('#\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp|tiff|ico)$#', $name);
}

usort($arquivos, function ($value) {
    return !is_image_extension($value);
});

foreach ($arquivos as $arq) {
    if (is_image_extension($arq)) { //Verifica se a extensão é imagem
        echo '<img src="../images/documentos/', $arq, '" />';
    }else{
        echo '<li>', $arq, '</li>';
    }
}
```

Note que a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) que usei `\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp|tiff|ico)$` checa todos nomes pelo final, tendo que ser .png, .jpg, etc, e usei o `!` na frente para inverter a ordem para que as imagens sejam as primeiras.

Exemplo online no [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/repls/AttentiveCompleteKillerwhale) e no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/An5QZ6)